# API Level 29 - MediaProjection is always requesting permission

Tags: android, android-mediaprojection

until Android API28 when requesting Media Projection Services android allowed the user to grant access just once by selecting "*Don't show again*" check-box. So that everytime app wants to use media projection services the access was already granted.

[image: Android AP28 - Media Services Diaglog]

In the android AP29 the dialog changed and this option does not exist anymore. 
[image: Android API29 - Media Services Dialog]

**What can be done in order to the user just grant the access once to the app to use media projection? Thank you.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the problem was that I was calling

```
startActivityForResult(mProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), REQUEST_CODE);
```

every time, which is not necessary (createScreenCaptureIntent() leads to the dialog window which requests user interaction) My solution makes the dialog appear only once (if application was closed it will ask for permission one time again). All I had to do was making addiotional private static variables of type Intent and int.

```
private static Intent staticIntentData;
private static int staticResultCode;
```

On Activity result I assign those variables with the passed result code and intent:

```
if(staticResultCode == 0 && staticIntentData == null) {
    sMediaProjection = mProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);
    staticIntentData = data;
    staticResultCode = resultCode;
} else {
    sMediaProjection = mProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(staticResultCode, staticIntentData)};
}
```

Every time I call my startprojection method, I will check if they are null:

```
if(staticIntentData == null)
        startActivityForResult(mProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), REQUEST_CODE);
        else
        captureScreen();
```

If null it will request permission, if not it will start the projection with the static intent data and static int resultcode, so it is not needed to ask for that permission again, just reuse what you get in activity result.

```
sMediaProjection = mProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(staticResultCode, staticIntentData);
```

Simple as that! Now it will only showing one single time each time you use the app. I guess thats what Google wants, because there no keep decision checkbox in that dialog like in previous android versions

Answer (score 0):

Static will be lost when the app restart or the phone reboot.
It is not good solution

Comment: This doesn't look like a separate answer, rather this is a comment to question/another answer.